# Jenkins failing while compiling

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project test-controller: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /root/.jenkins/workspace/userapp/test-api/test-controller/src/main/java/com/testproject/test/controller/CorsConfig.java:[17,65] ')' expected
```

line 17 is
registry.addMapping( pathPattern: "/**")

Comment: Lesson 0: tools usually don't lie in error messages. If the compiler claims there's a syntax error then 99 out of a 100 times there's a syntax error. What does line 17 (and the surrounding ones) of `CorsConfig` look like.

Comment: In the case of syntax errors it is far more like 1,000,000 out of 1,000,000, even if you think otherwise, You need to produce the code, otherwise your question will be closed.

Comment: here is what I have on line 17 

registry.addMapping( pathPattern: "/**")

Comment: That's not legal Java code. The compiler is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have an error in `CorsConfig.java`, at line 17, character 65. A closing `)` was expected and not found. Just as the error message states. Fix it before running Jenkins.

Comment: registry.addMapping( pathPattern: "/**")

Comment: the above is line 17

Comment: Aren't you a java developer?

Comment: I am a server admin trying to fix the Jenkins issue, not a developer :(

Comment: Well it isn't legal Java code. Find a Java developer, and don't fiddle with things you don't understand. And don't claim there are no syntax errors if you aren't competent to judge. This is a developer's problem, not yours.

Comment: so, you need find the developer to resolve this error. only one line, the others can't help you .